# How to get rust struct associated function, struct method or trait method to be exported function in wasm32

Tags: rust, webassembly

I am trying to create a series of functions (that are implementations of a trait).
Each one will get compiled to a wasm module. Later each module is loaded and the same function called (by name) on each of them.

I'd like a function in wasm that is a trait method, 
as I also compile and call the function via trait objects when
all is compiled to rust also.

I couldn't get it working with a trait method, so I simplified
down to just an associated function (or method, same problem) on a struct.

It seems that when I implement a function on a struct, the function is
not compiled to wasm and/or not exported.

Anyone know how to achieve what I describe above?

`Cargo.toml` is:

```
[package]
name = "add_function"
version = "0.0.1"

[lib]
name = "add_function"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
path = "src/add_function.rs"
```

and I compile to wasm32-unknown-unknown (via a .cargo/config file)

## Standalone Function

### add_function.rs

```
pub struct Add;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn run_wasm(a: u32, b: u32) -> u32 {
 // removed for brevity
}

impl Add { // this can be removed - just to make more similar to second example below
}
```

### Output from wasm-objdump

```
...
Export[5]:
 - memory[0] -> "memory"
 - global[1] -> "__heap_base"
 - global[2] -> "__data_end"
 - global[3] -> "__rustc_debug_gdb_scripts_section__"
 - func[40] <run_wasm> -> "run_wasm"
...
```

## Function in impl (Associated Function)

### add_function.rs

```
pub struct Add;

impl Add {
    #[no_mangle]
    pub extern "C" fn run_wasm(a: u32, b: u32) -> u32 {
        // removed for brevity
        // adding "&self" to make a method does not change anything
    }
}
```

### Output from wasm-obj-dump

```
Export[4]:
 - memory[0] -> "memory"
 - global[1] -> "__heap_base"
 - global[2] -> "__data_end"
 - global[3] -> "__rustc_debug_gdb_scripts_section__"
```

Comment: How do you expect to use it? You can't pass a rust struct to an exported function anyway.

Comment: Well that's a whole different story, and the plan is to serialize structs to linear memory and work from there... But in the reduced examples as you can see the in the signature I pass two u32 (should be i32 I think) and return one u32. If I get that working I'll take it from there.

Comment: Are you using `wasm-bindgen` or raw `wasm` bindings?

Comment: No wasm-bindgen in this project (no JS involved) just what you see above for the rust-wasm side, then loading the wasm module and executing it via wasmi (which works fine if the function is exported).

Comment: But how do you intend to call a method of a struct from wasm? As far as I know, wasm interfaces are just like C ones, that is plain namespaceless functions.

Comment: Yes, but a .rs file with a 'pub extern "C" fn XXX' could make XXX an exported function, no? Or it could call it StructName_XXX, or some such scheme.

Comment: What I usually do is to write a free function `pub extern "C" fn StructName_xxx(s: &StructName) { s.xxx() }` that forwards to the non-extern member function. I've never seen an extern member function and I doubt that it can be done. In fact I'm surprised that you do not get a compiler error.